# Prevent empty lines from output in node readline

Tags: node.js, stream, readline

When I press and hold ENTER on my keyboard, the readline module will then output empty lines to my writeable stream(in this case it is process.stdout).

But since I don't want empty lines to clutter my console I want to prevent it somehow from being outputted.

Can I use something to filter out empty lines in my stream? Maybe using a transform stream of some sorts?

```js
const readline = require("readline");

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  removeHistoryDuplicates: true
});

rl.on("line", (line) => {
  if(line.trim().length === 0) {
    // don't output anything, but it is already too late because it is already written to stream :'-(
  }
  rl.prompt();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
   readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0,0);
```

enter will automatically be ignored and return to the begining

https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline_clearline_stream_dir

```
const readline = require("readline");

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  removeHistoryDuplicates: true
});


const enterPressed=(line)=>{
    return line.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "").trim().length === 0
}

rl.on("line", (line) => {

  if(enterPressed(line)) {
     readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0,0);
  }
  rl.prompt();
})
```

Comment: What does this line really mean? `return line.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "").trim().length === 0`

Comment: just test that enter is pressed remove all non alpha chrs

Comment: doesn't appear to work. well, it erases all visible console output before that. I took a gif: https://i.imgur.com/1QrgWGw.gif

Comment: readline.cursorTo(<READ_LINE_STREAM>, 0, <NUMBER_OF_LINES> .  set NUMBER_OF_LINES to the last line insted of 0

Comment: Is it possible to get the last line? I looked for a way in node but I couldn't find it. :-(